# How to for loop array in collection laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I store my array in config/product.php

```
return [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'test1',
        'name' => 'name1'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'title' => 'test2',
        'name' => 'name2'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'title' => "test3",
        'name' => 'name3'
    ]
];
```

In My controller I use pluck to show my title

```
  $product = collect(config('products'))->pluck('title','id');
    $data['product'] = $product;
    $data['store'] = $this->store;
    return view($this->route.'.create',$data);
```

in my view

```
{!!
    Form::select('product',$product, null, [
        'placeholder' => 'Select Product',
        'class' => [
            'form-control',
            $errors->has('product') ? 'is-invalid' : '',
        ],
    ]);
!!}
```

But in this way It'll display only title How can I display Name and title some thing like this

```
 Form::select('product',$product->title.$product, null, [
        'placeholder' => 'Select Product',
        'class' => [
            'form-control',
            $errors->has('product') ? 'is-invalid' : '',
        ],
    ]);
```

Comment: Generate select manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, change the pluck to entail the name as well.

```
 $product = collect(config('products'))->pluck('title', 'name', 'id');
```

Or retrieve the whole model if it makes more sense.

Then, for every element on your form, you need to make different selects.

```
Form::select('product',$product->title, null, [
    'placeholder' => 'Select Product Title',
    'class' => [
        'form-control',
        $errors->has('product') ? 'is-invalid' : '',
    ],
]);
```

So you need to have this code snippet for

```
$product->title and $product->name.
```

You could also use model binding:
https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#form-model-binding

Don't forget to read this important part when using model binding.

> Now, when you generate a form element, like a text input, the model's value matching the field's name will automatically be set as the field value. So, for example, for a text input named  email, the user model's email attribute would be set as the value. However, there's more! If there is an item in the Session flash data matching the input name, that will take precedence over the model's value.

So you will need to open the model first.

```
echo Form::model($user, array('route' => array('user.update', $user->id)))
```

Then you need to make the correct select fields in this form as well.
In your example it would be:

```
echo Form::text('title');
echo Form::text('name');
```

Full example:

```
{{ Form::model($product, ['route' => ['product.update', $product->id]]); }}
{{ Form::text('title'); }}
{{ Form::text('name'); }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller get the whole array of products.

```
$products = collect(config('products'));
```

In your blade

```
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::Label('Product', 'Products:') !!}
<select class="form-control" name="item_id">
   @foreach($products as $product)
     <option value="{{ $product['id'] }}">{{  $product['name']." ".$product['title']   }}</option>
   @endforeach 
</select>
```

Try this

Comment: This is only half of a full answer. He is also confused on how to display all the data. I don't think you want a select that can select between name/title of one object. It doesn't make sense. If I'm correct you need more Form elements than just one.

Comment: @Kerel I hope you read this line from question "But in this way It'll display only title How can I display Name and title some thing like this"

Comment: Yes I did, and  "Form::select('product',$product, null, ..." is not gonna work for multiple fields. You need more of these.

Comment: Updated for a change